# LINQ - Convert LINQ select to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dataset

I have a class that does some validation on the data. I want to reuse that class from a different place.
I cant change that class. 
It goes something like:

```
public static List<string> Validate(DataTable CurrentMasterTable, Dictionary<string, string[]> LocalMasterRuleSet)
    {...}
```

In its own it works just fine.

Issue is in the following. From another place in the project, to use that class, I must send it DataTable object, so it can do its magic.

How can I use LINQ, make selection on the table and send it as DataTable?
I have this code to begin with:

```
  var listOfSinglePropertyNames = (from x in dbContext.tbl_mytable.AsEnumerable()                                             select x);

        IEnumerable<tbl_mytable> query = listOfSinglePropertyNames;
```

How do I convert the query to DataTable object? Reading other posts, I have seen I should use CopyToDataTable();

But I am not having any success.

Comment: I have reworked the question to show that I made research before posting :)

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526726/linq-to-sql-convert-iqueryable-to-dataset).. If you skip the `AsEnumerable()` maybe the other questions answer(s) could work?

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ to datatable. Adapt this code for your needings:

```
 // Query the SalesOrderHeader table for orders placed 
// after August 8, 2001.
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
where order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate") > new DateTime(2001, 8, 1)
select order;

// Create a table from the query.
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```